# How to get text to span a single line?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to get text to disapre on smaller screen sizes, from lg to small, it works but text spans two lines when I add the effect.

When I add `d-lg-block` it starts to span two lines.

**I have tried the following:**

- `display: inline;`

Problem code:

```
<span class="d-none d-lg-block">6*7*******</span>
```

Full code: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/A1dc0qi7nIeaDaJqM9O1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">
```

This is what you're looking for! :) However, the CSS would have been

```
display: inline-block!important;
```

Without the important, I think Bootstrap's CSS would have overridden yours anyway.